# Samsung Smart TV emulator can't connect to network

Tags: virtualbox, samsung-smart-tv

I have an issue where my Samsung Smart TV emulator v 5.1 no longer connects to the network and as such I can't test apps whether launching from Eclipse or Standalone

I am running it on OS X Mavericks and have tried both the latest versions of VirtualBox (4.3) and the Samsung compatibility version. (4.2.1.6)

Answer (score 1):

What I found was the issue is don't let VirtualBox generate a new MAC address, once that is happened the network will never connect and there doesn't appear to be a way to get into the VM and fix as you would on a linux.

Fix is to delete your OVA/VMDK and install a new one downloaded from the Samsung site.