# Not able to get connect network connection on Samsung Smart TV emulator

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-emulator

I am using Tizen SDK IDE version 2.4.0_Rev5 for windows7 64-bit downloaded from the SamsungDForum website.

I am testing on Samsung Tizen TV emulator (Samsung TV SDK Extension Image- Windows7 64-bit) downloaded from the same website.

I was initially testing with the sample Apps for AVPlay framework but I was not able to play any videos since the prepare() call was failing.

I suspected it could be due to network connection issues for the emulator. So I tried with this sample App provided to check network connectivity:
https://github.com/SamsungDForum/NetworkSample And the sample app indicates that there is no network connection.

So my questions are:
1) Is my inference that the emulator is not connected to network correct?
2) Is there a simpler/more direct way of checking for network connection on the emulator?
3) Assuming it is an issue with network connection(which I highly suspect), how can I fix this?
I went through this question on StackOverflow:
[Samsung Smart TV emulator can't connect to network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005617/samsung-smart-tv-emulator-cant-connect-to-network)
It seemed to suggest that it the emulator and PC have different MAC addresses, then emulator will not be able to connect to network.
Is this correct?
If yes then how can I do that, this answer was for using emulator with a virtual box, which is no long now.

Comment: Note: The Tizen SDK IDE and the Tizen TV emulator were downloaded from: 
https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenDevtools/SdkDownload
and the Sample Apps for playing videos using AvPlay framwork were taken from :
https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenSampleGuide/tizen3461/index.html

Answer (score 4):

When creating the emulator set the proxy parameter as : Use host proxy, and Connect type as NAT.
Then, in the config.xml file add this:

```html
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

.

If you want a sample app to test connectivity, create a new app with index.xml containig the following :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:white;">Test connectivity</a>
</body>
```

don't forget to add the following in the config.xml file:

```html
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work. I suspect the issue could be related to proxy, but I don't know. My network is behind a proxy. If I change the proxy setting to 'No proxy', then I am able to access files in the local Lan.

Answer (score 1):

By default the emulator will use whatever your computer's connection is. However, you have to allow the app running in the emulator to access the Internet. I checked the sample apps you linked to and they do not have the following items configured.

First, make sure you set the appropriate [W3C Access Requests Policy (WARP)](https://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-access/) for the site(s) you will be accessing. The following grants unlimited access (which you should not do for a production app) in the config.xml file in the root directory:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Next, you must also add the Tizen Internet access privilege in the config.xml file. The following allows Internet access:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

[See all Tizen privileges](https://www.tizen.org/privilege).